# Why occurrence runtime error in c language coding?

Tags: c, arrays

Why occurrence runtime error in c language coding?

The answer is correct, but I have a runtime error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[10]= {0};
    int a = 0,b = 0;
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    arr[0] = a;
    arr[1] = b;
    for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        arr[i+2]=arr[i]+arr[i+1];
        if(arr[i] > 10)
            arr[i] = arr[i] % 10;

        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Because you trying to access array element with index > 10(array out of bounds), at line 9.

Comment: You need to check the return value of scanf to make sure you have two valid integers in *a* and *b*.

Answer (score 2):

You have a memory overrun in your code. Say, in the loop, when `i` is `8`,

```
arr[i+2]=arr[i]+arr[i+1];
```

you're trying to access `arr[10]` in `arr[i+2]`, which is a out of bound access, causing [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should change your loop condition to

```
for (int i = 0; i <8; i++)
```

to keep the indexes between `0`-`9`.